# Cakephp 2.5 AuthComponent is null after login

Tags: cakephp

excuse me for my English, I'm French.

Well, my login function returns TRUE, and I am connected.

But when I inspect the variable $ this-> Auth-> user, the result is empty.

Why?

**//AppController.php**

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
         'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'E-Mail',
                    'password' => 'MPDweb'
                )
            )
        ),  
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display',        'home')
    )
);
```

**//login.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('E-Mail', array('class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus')); ?>
<br />
<?php echo $this->Form->input('MPDweb', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<br />
<?php echo $this->Form->button('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**//UsersController.php**

```
public function login(){
// var_dump($this->request->data);
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if($this->Auth->login()){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Vous êtes bien connecter');
        var_dump($this->Auth->login());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Inentifiant ou mot de passe incorrect');
    }
    // debug($this->Auth->login());
}
}
```

**//User.php**

```
 App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
//App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class User extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'prospect';
    public $primaryKey = 'code_client';

}
```

NB: For the moment, I do not encode the password with the method "hash"

Comment: `var_dump($this->Auth->login());` should be `var_dump($this->Auth->user());`

Comment: Are your database field named `E-Mail` and `MPDweb`? Unless it's a legacy db which you cannot modify follow CakePHP's conventions and use underscored field names.

Comment: "For the moment, I do not encode the password with the method 'hash'". Well that isn't going to work since by default Auth will use SimplePasswordHasher and hash the password coming from login form before comparing to value from database.

Comment: Great ! "should be var_dump($this->Auth->user());"

Comment: I work on an existing database and I can not change the name of the field. 
I would have liked to follow the conventions of Cakephp but I can not.